# Reflexive sheaf on normal surfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, coherent-sheaves

Let $X$ be a normal, projective scheme of pure dimension $2$ and $\mathcal{F}$ is a reflexive coherent sheaf on $X$. Is $\mathcal{F}$ locally free?

Comment: No.  Try googling examples of reflexive sheaves.

Answer (score 3):

No. In fact, rank 1 reflexive $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules correspond to linear equivalence classes of *Weil* divisors, while the locally free ones correspond to Cartier divisors -- see e.g. the Appendix to §1 in Reid's *Canonical 3-folds*. If  for instance $X$ is a quadratic cone, the reflexive rank 1 sheaf associated to a generatrix is not locally free.